# android billing item is purchased but there is no connection

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Lets consider following situation:

1. User installed application from Android Market and bought some item (so this item is binded to his account).
2. Then he uninstalled application
3. Then he installed it again (in this case user has already bought the item, so info about item should be available after start). But before run internet connection was lost.

If code of application checks purchased items, then without connection it will be impossible to check it.

**What is the approach to handle such situation?**

**Is any way to check it when application is running first time after installation but there is no connection?**

Answer (score 2):

If he already bought the item, the info will be cached by the Google Play app. Next time when your app launched be it uninstalled and re-installed, when the app queries for purchase info, the info, you'll get the purchase info. It does not require an internet connection. You can query for existing purchases at every app launch.

Comment: thanks Kadaj for your response,

you wrote: `If he already bought the item, the info will be cached by the Google Play app.`
Maybe I'm wrong but cache exists till the device will be rebooted.
So lets assume that user rebooted device and forgot to turn interner on :) and then run application

Comment: I didn't know that a phone reboot wipes the cache. Are you sure about that? Usually cache has to be manually cleared from app settings or the play store app itself. If by that logic, then all app's cache would get cleared on reboot which I think is kind of dumb. But to the point, if cache gets cleared and there is no internet connection, then there is no way the app can get the in-app purchase info. The app cannot communicate to your own server too. If you want to know if app had run for the first time, you can make use of filesystem but if cache gets cleared I guess that would be a problem.